# Header Text appearing outside of its Div (Mozilla firefox). No issue with chrome/IE

Tags: javascript, html, css, mozilla

The issue is with the h5 text not appearing within the div (id=text). if anyone could advise please! Thank you for reading this and taking your time to help!

```
<div id="footer">
    <div id="instagram">
        <div id="text">
            <h5>Please follow our <a href="https://www.instagram.com/craftyclams/">instagram</a> for future updates !</h5>
        </div>
        <div id="insta-logo">
            <div>
                <a class="whitelink" href="https://www.instagram.com/craftyclams/" id="insta"></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS code for footer:**

[image]

**Where the div is positioned:**

[image]

Comment: why are you displaying the text div as a table cell? also have you tried to take the top padding off of that element?

Answer (score 0):

From what I see, your text is inside the div. I set up a jsfiddle for you: https://jsfiddle.net/vfakqg90/

Next time, please provide your CSS, not as a screenshot. I typed your CSS out fully.

If you can, provide your full HTML and CSS so I can take a further look. For now, I don't see a problem according to the jsfiddle I put together for you. The CSS you provided as a screenshot is below for others:

```
div#footer {
    width: 100%;
    height: 7%;
    background: url("footerbg.jpg");
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    min-width: 1380px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    }
div#instagram {
    width: 80%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: table;
    table-layout: fixed;
    }
div#instagram div#text {
    width: 70%;
    height: 100%;
    padding-top: 15px;
    display: table-cell;
    }
div#instagram div#text h5 {
    font-family: BRUX, serif;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 1.7em;
    }
h5 a {
    font-family: BRUX, serif;
    color: #fff;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #fff;
    padding-bottom: 3px;
    }
div#instagram div#insta-logo div {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding-top: 30px;
    }
#insta {
    background: url("logo/insta_icon.png");
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    display: block;
    height: 90%;
    text-indent: 100%;
    white-space: nowrap;
    width: 70%;
    max-width: 250px;
    max-height: 250px;
    }
```